# turning on gzip cuts the response from upstream

Tags: nginx

My upstream server returns extremely large JSON responses (5~8GB).
I'm trying to condense those responses by enabling gzip on nginx. This is my config

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    
    location / {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 1;
        gzip_types *;
        gzip_proxied any;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}
```

This config technically works. At least, it works for smaller responses (~150MB before compression). When I try to download large response (~7.5GB before compression)

`curl -v --compressed --output /path_to_file -X POST http://localhost:8080 --data '{data}'`

It gets cut off in the middle, i.e. I see this message from curl

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

and the response itself is incomplete (on average it only downloads ~5.3GB out of ~7.5GB)

I also see this log from nginx

```
2022/04/20 01:18:45 [error] 37#37: *135 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

I tried increasing `proxy_max_temp_file_size`, and, I tried disabling buffering. nothing works

Any ideas?

Edit: this is the `nginx.conf` that's built in in the docker image I'm using

```
worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log" main;
    add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    tcp_nodelay        off;
    gzip               on;
    gzip_http_version  1.0;
    gzip_comp_level    2;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers        HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    client_max_body_size 80M;
    server_tokens off;

    absolute_redirect  off;
    port_in_redirect   off;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

    # HTTP Server
    server {
        # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
        listen  8080;

        include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";

        location /status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set `proxy_send_timeout` (default 60 seconds) accordingly and check your error.log

Comment: @user973254 I tried setting `proxy_send_timeout` to an high number, still getting the same error (`upstream prematurely closed connection while...`)

Comment: could you provide your nginx config fully?

Comment: @user973254 this is actually the entire config. i'm using the `bitnami/nginx` docker image and I load the file I pasted above into the container via volumes. are there any other config files that I could look at?

Comment: `The default nginx.conf includes server blocks placed in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/` taken from here https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/nginx

Comment: @user973254 got it. updated the post

Comment: ok, try to add `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; proxy_buffering off;` also please add contents of `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf`

Answer (score 0):

in similar case this line in location block solved the problem

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

it seems like gzip'ed response somehow incompatible with http2